# Wanting Excel to cut and paste a row of information when criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spread sheet set up for my partner's home business where she can input data relating to people joining the business. I am looking to have the data from that row cut and paste to a separate sheet depending on the criteria in one of the cells. The main sheet is called "Workspace".

If the person on row 6 has agreed to join the business then a "Yes" would be placed in cell V6. Once the Yes has been input I am aiming for the columns A:G to be cut and paste onto the sheet "Joined" as well as the rest of that row being deleted and preferably the rows underneath moving up one (if that is possible). The data would be pasted onto the next blank row on the "Joined" sheet.

On the flip side, if the person on row 6 states they are uninterested then a "Not Interested" would be placed in cell H6. Once the not interested has been input I am aiming for the columns A:G to be cut and paste onto the sheet "Not Interested" as well as the rest of that row being deleted, like above.

Is it also possible to have the spread sheet sort names alphabetically each time a new name is added? The starting row for data is 6.

I hope this all makes sense and really hope someone is able to assist. I am quite good when it comes to formulas but not got a clue where to start with regards to macros.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets("Workspace").Range("V:V")
If Cell.Value = "Yes" Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Joined").Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Workspace").Select
End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image: Current Spreadsheet]

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to tell you that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You should at least have some code to start with. If you need to learn VBA this might be the wrong place. People usually come here with specific problems in their code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Peh. Is there anywhere you could point me to try and solve my problem?

Comment: OK I have no idea what you are trying to do. You can read [ask] to see how to write a good question. Try to shorten it, bring it to a specific point. Try to illustrate what you have and what you like to achieve. Screenshots might help a lot. I think much text and many cell addresses without seeing a sheet is really cumbersome.

Comment: My code so far.

Comment: Really, are you kidding? I'm sorry, but I'm not gonna try to read this at all. There is an edit button to edit the question. Put the code in a **nicely formatted** way into the question and try to illustrate what you have and what you like to achieve (with a screenshot). If you don't write a good and precise question I see no chance to get any help here.

Comment: I apologise regarding the comment. It showed fine on my computer until I refreshed the page. Have edited my original post.

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better, but a screenshot of your sheet would still be very helpful. It's hard to imagine how the data looks like if you can only read text. It's easy for you to imagine because you know how it looks like. But keep in mind that we have never seen your sheet.

Comment: Have now added a picture highlighting the column I am trying to read data from. Hoping this helps. Really appreciate your assistance so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good starting point for you. I added comments to the code so you can see what every line does.

This sub searches for "yes" in column V and copies Range A:G of the columns with "yes" into sheet Joined. Then it deletes the entire row where the "yes" was found.

I think from here you can do the second part for "Not Accepted" on your own.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MatchRow As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Destination As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Workspace") 'define ws as sheet workspace (shortcut)

    FirstRow = 6 'First row with data below headline
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row 'Get last used row in column V (so we don't need to go through the full column)

    Dim i As Long
    i = FirstRow
    Do While i <= LastRow 'start searching for "Yes" in FirstRow and end in LastRow
        If ws.Range("V" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
            MatchRow = ws.Range("V" & i).Row 'remember matched row number

            'find last free row in column A of sheet Joined and remember in Destination
            With Sheets("Joined")
                Set Destination = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With

            'Copy range A:G from matched row to destination found above
            ws.Range("A" & MatchRow & ":G" & MatchRow).Copy Destination

            'Delete copied entire row
            ws.Rows(MatchRow).EntireRow.Delete

            'reduce LastRow by one (because we deleted one row)
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else
            'go to next row
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Peh. That worked perfectly. I have managed to complete the rest by myself thanks to your assistance. I really appreciate all the help you provided.